# how can setup.py sdist dereference symbolic links?

Tags: setuptools, distutils, python-packaging

The `setup.cfg` section `data_files` contains a directory with symbolic links. When running `python setup.py sdist`, the resulting distribution does not contain the symbolic links, they are ignored. Here is the content of `setup.py`, based on [pbr](https://github.com/openstack/pbr):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup

setup(
    setup_requires=['pbr'],
    pbr=True,
)
```

It would be fine to dereference the symbolic links and include the actual file instead. The distribution would be bigger because files are duplicated, but it would be complete.

Looking at the [sdist sources](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/distutils/command/sdist.py#L452) it is looks like the symbolic links are always ignored:

```sh
$ python setup.py sdist
...
'molecule/debops' not a regular file -- skipping
...
```

Is there a workaround to convince `sdist` to dereference the symbolic links?

Comment: Is this only when using `distutils` directly? Or also when using `setuptools`?

Comment: The message above is [from distutils](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/distutils/command/sdist.py#L452)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MANIFEST.in [graft command](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html#commands) is unfortunately not in the [python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/distutils/sourcedist.html), but can be found [in the sources](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bd48d27944453ad83d3ce37b2c867fa0d59a1c15/Lib/distutils/filelist.py#L162). It calls [include_pattern](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bd48d27944453ad83d3ce37b2c867fa0d59a1c15/Lib/distutils/filelist.py#L180) and [findall](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bd48d27944453ad83d3ce37b2c867fa0d59a1c15/Lib/distutils/filelist.py#L213) which [follows symbolic links](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bd48d27944453ad83d3ce37b2c867fa0d59a1c15/Lib/distutils/filelist.py#L252). It is therefore enough to add the following line to `MANIFEST.in`:

```
graft molecule/
```

to ensure the `molecule/` tree is included in the distribution and that all symbolic links will be followed. This indeed leads to duplicate content but the result is complete.

The root cause of the symbolic link suppression is that (unlike to `sdist`) `pbr` walks the directories mentionned in `data_files` [without following symbolic links](https://github.com/openstack/pbr/blob/55429ef85692298a6f2dacb38bfa27f2aac5477f/pbr/hooks/files.py#L60). It will therefore create a list of paths in the SOURCES.txt file that contain symbolic links. And they will be [ignored by sdist](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/distutils/command/sdist.py#L452) and never make it to the distribution.